# Using Spring Batch JdbcCursorItemReader with NamedParameters

Tags: spring-batch

The Spring Batch **JdbcCursorItemReader** can accept a **preparedStatementSetter**:

```
<bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="..." />
   <property name="sql" value="SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 = ?">
   <property name="rowMapper" ref="..." />
   <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="..." />
</bean>
```

This works well if the sql uses **?** as placeholder(s), as in the above example. However, our pre-existing sql uses named parameters, e.g. SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 = **:param**
.

Is there a way to get a JdbcCursorItemReader to work with a **NamedPreparedStatementSetter** rather than a simple PreparedStatementSetter?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post code to show how you done this without jobParameters ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `jobParameters`. In this case you don't need any `PreparedStatementSetter`.

```
<bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="..." />
   <property name="sql" value="SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 = #{jobParameters['col1']">
   <property name="rowMapper" ref="..." />
   <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="..." />
</bean>
```

pass the value when running the job

```
JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("col1", "value1").toJobParameters();

JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
```

Comment: It doesn't work in my case :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008631/pass-parameters-in-spring-data

Answer (score 3):

Once we don't have an official solution from spring, we can fix this problem using a simple approach:

1. Define one interface to provide the SqlParameters:

```java
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;

public interface SqlParameterSourceProvider { 
    SqlParameterSource getSqlParameterSource();
}
```

2. Extending the **JdbcCursorItemReader** and adding the namedParameter features.

```java
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlTypeValue;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.*;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;


public class NamedParameterJdbcCursorItemReader<T> extends JdbcCursorItemReader<T> {

    private SqlParameterSourceProvider parameterSourceProvider;
    private String paramedSql;

    public NamedParameterJdbcCursorItemReader(SqlParameterSourceProvider parameterSourceProvider) {
        this.parameterSourceProvider = parameterSourceProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSql(String sql) {
        Assert.notNull(parameterSourceProvider, "You have to set parameterSourceProvider before the SQL statement");
        Assert.notNull(sql, "sql must not be null");
        paramedSql = sql;
        super.setSql(NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters(sql, parameterSourceProvider.getSqlParameterSource()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyStatementSettings(PreparedStatement stmt) throws SQLException {
        final ParsedSql parsedSql = NamedParameterUtils.parseSqlStatement(paramedSql);

        final List<?> parameters = Arrays.asList(NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(parsedSql, parameterSourceProvider.getSqlParameterSource(), null));
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.size(); i++) {
            StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(stmt, i + 1, SqlTypeValue.TYPE_UNKNOWN, parameters.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

3. Creating the concrete class that implements the interface **SqlParameterSourceProvider** and has the state with the updated value of the parameters to be used in your query.

```java
public class MyCustomSqlParameterSourceProvider implements SqlParameterSourceProvider {

    private Map<String, Object> params;

    public void updateParams(Map<String, Object> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    @Override
    public SqlParameterSource getSqlParameterSource() {
        final MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        paramSource.addValues(params);
        return paramSource;
    }
}
```

4. Finally, update the spring configuration.

```xml
<bean id="reader" class="org.wisecoding.stackoverflow.NamedParameterJdbcCursorItemReader">
    <constructor-arg ref="sqlParameterSourceProvider"/>        
    <property name="dataSource" ref="..." />
    <property name="sql" value=SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 = :param" />
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="..." />
    <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="..." />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlParameterSourceProvider" class="org.wisecoding.stackoverflow.MyCustomSqlParameterSourceProvider">
</bean>
```

Comment: As Michael Minella suggested, I have created a ticket [on Spring Batch Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2521) and also created [a branch of the spring batch on github](https://github.com/wbsouza/spring-batch) adding this feature.

Comment: As explained in https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2521, there is a simpler way to achieve the desired feature without introducing a new interface (`SqlParameterSourceProvider`),  extending the `JdbcCursorItemReader` and implementing a custom `SqlParameterSourceProvider`. Hope it helps.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine It works when we have param as single value. But when I pass a list as one of the values, I am missing something on how I can leverage the solution pasted in your link above.

Comment: @NeerajSingh I believe you are referring to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782690. As I mentioned in the answer to that question, the same solution works by flattening parameters or by using a `PreparedStatementCreatorFactory` as shown here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57471284/5019386. I added an example for both cases in this [repo](https://github.com/benas/sandbox/blob/master/batch2521).

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is not a way to do this.  The JdbcCursorItemReader uses raw JDBC (PreparedStatement) instead of the Spring JdbcTemplate under the hood (since there is no way to get the underlying ResultSet when using JdbcTemplate).  If you'd like to contribute this as a new feature, or request it as a new feature, feel free to do so at [jira.spring.io](http://jira.spring.io)

Comment: @Michael Minella - Is this feature has been developed in Spring Batch version 4.0.x ? Could you please show the code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

original solution in https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2521, but which does not support `id in (:ids)` clause.

here is an enhancement.

```
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import lombok.val;

import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils;

import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
public class NamedParameterJdbcCursorItemReader<T> extends JdbcCursorItemReader<T> {

    protected void setNamedParametersSql(String sql, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        val parsedSql = NamedParameterUtils.parseSqlStatement(sql);
        val paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource(parameters);

        val sqlToUse = NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters(parsedSql, paramSource);
        val declaredParams = NamedParameterUtils.buildSqlParameterList(parsedSql, paramSource);
        val params = NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(parsedSql, paramSource, null);
        val pscf = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(sql, declaredParams);
        val pss = pscf.newPreparedStatementSetter(params);

        log.info("sql: {}", sqlToUse);
        log.info("parameters: {}", parameters);

        setSql(sqlToUse);
        setPreparedStatementSetter(pss);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Slf4j
public class UserItemJdbcReader extends NamedParameterJdbcCursorItemReader<UserEntity> {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        val sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (:ids)";

        val parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>(4);
        parameters.put("ids", Arrays.asList(1,2,3));

        setDataSource(dataSource);
        setRowMapper(new UserRowMapper());
        setNamedParametersSql(sql, parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to know how we can use this to return the data as an ItemReader

Answer (score 0):

in my case I reuse `ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter` from spring-jdbc

```
    private static final String SQL = "SELECT * FROM payments.transactions WHERE time_stamp >= ? AND time_stamp <= ?";
...
        Object[] args = new Object[2];
        args[0] = new Date(Instant.now().minus(7, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli());
        args[1] = new Date();
        ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter argumentPreparedStatementSetter =
                new ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter(args);

        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<>()
                .name("dbReader")
                .sql(SQL)
                .preparedStatementSetter(argumentPreparedStatementSetter)
        ...
```