# Spring Batch Database Dependency pass parameters to SQL statement

Tags: spring-batch

I want separate the sql from the batch.xml file, so I defined the sql statement into a properties file. Inside the batch.xml I bind the property-placeholder bean then point to the properties file.

For simple select statement should not be a problem. But if I want to pass the parameter as where clause condition is it possible to do that?

```
<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:batch-sql.properties/>

<bean id="secondReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql" value="${sql1}" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.test.batchjob.process.TestPersonMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is my sql statment in properties file:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE id = ?
```

Can the id pass from jobparameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the parameters of the query in a `JdbcPagingItemReader`, you have to use the property `parametersValue`. This property takes a `Map<String,Object>` where the key is either the named parameter or the index of the parameter (if you use `?`).

```
<bean id="secondReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="queryProvider">
          <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="selectClause" value="select *" />
            <property name="fromClause" value="from persons" />
            <property name="whereClause" value="where id = ?" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="parametersValue">
        <map>
            <entry key="1" value="#{jobParameters['id']}" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.test.batchjob.process.TestPersonMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

See documentation : [JdbcPagingItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html#setParameterValues-java.util.Map-)

**UPDATE**

You have to use a `QueryProvider` instead of `sql` and `datasource` properties.
You can replace the text of the query by values of the properties file.

Comment: I having this error "Invalid property 'sql' of bean class [org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader]: Bean property 'sql' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?" When changing JdbcCursorItemReader to JdbcPagingItemReader

Comment: @EinnHann Right, `JdbcPagingItemReader` doesn't have a `sql`property. You have to use a `QueryProvider`. See updated answer.

Comment: Because my sql have to retrieve from properties file. So, does it mean I need to declare select from and where separately in properties file?

Comment: @EinnHann Yes, I think you have to. But there may exist another solution. Also, I see you updated your question with a `JdbcCursorItemReader` which works a bit differently. I'll post another answer for this case then.

Answer (score 0):

To set the parameters of the query in a `JdbcCursorItemReader`, you have to use the property `preparedStatementSetter`. This property takes a `PreparedStatementSetter` which you have to implement yourself to set either named or index-based parameters.

```
<bean id="secondReader"
class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"
scope="step">
<property name="sql" value="${sql1}" />
<property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
    <bean class="xx.xx.xx.YourPreparedStatementSetter">
        <property name="id" value="#{jobParameters['id']}" />
    </bean>
</property>
<property name="rowMapper">
    <bean class="com.test.batchjob.process.TestPersonMapper" />
</property>
```

An example implementation of a `PreparedStatementSetter` :

```
public class YourPreparedStatementSetter implements PreparedStatementSetter {

    private String id;

    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
        ps.setString(1, this.id);
    }

    public setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `JdbcCursorItemReader`, you can take a look at answer here : [Using Spring Batch JdbcCursorItemReader with NamedParameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222353/using-spring-batch-jdbccursoritemreader-with-namedparameters)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question then [vote to close](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If the question is not a duplicate then tailor the answer to this specific question.