# Pass parameters in Spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I wonder how to pass parameter to bean.xml.

If I write like this in bean.xml, it works as expected

```
<bean id="notificationReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
     <property name="sql" value="SELECT r.EDCBATCH_OPEN_DATETIME As openDate FROM rev_acq_edcbatch r WHERE r.EDCBATCH_STATUS ='A'" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
    <bean name = "campaignMapper" class="rh.com.app.domain.AgingMapper">
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

But if I write like this, I get error

```
  <property name="sql" value="SELECT r.EDCBATCH_OPEN_DATETIME As openDate FROM rev_acq_edcbatch r WHERE r.EDCBATCH_STATUS = #{jobParameters['edcbatchStatus']}" />
```

My bean.xml

```
 <task:scheduled-tasks>
            <task:scheduled ref="agingScheduler" method="run" cron="*/5 * * * * *" /><!--0 0 5 * * *-->
        </task:scheduled-tasks>

 <!--        class = bean-->
    <bean id="agingScheduler" class="rh.com.ap.AgingScheduler">
        <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />   
        <property name="agingJob" ref="agingJob" /> 
        <property name="mailClient" ref="mailClient" /> 
    </bean> 


    <batch:job id="agingJob">
      <batch:step id="step1" next = "emailFile" >
                <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                    <batch:chunk reader="notificationReader" writer="notificationWriter" processor="notificationProcessor" commit-interval="10" />
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
            <batch:step id="emailFile">
                <batch:tasklet ref="emailTasklet" />
            </batch:step> 

            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="jobListener" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:job>
```

**AgingScheduler**

```
  JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
            builder.addDate("date", new Date());
            builder.addString("fileName", "AgingReporting_" + PropertiseUtil.settlementDateyyyyMMdd());
            builder.addString("edcbatchStatus","A").toJobParameters();
```

**Error**

```
Job failed with following exceptions 
exception :Failed to initialize the reader
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello John,

You could create a subclass of JdbcCursorItemReader where you set #{jobParameters['edcbatchStatus']}
as a seperate parameter. And then use Springs InitializingBean to set
the Sql property. How about something like this?

```
class EdcBatchStatusItemReader extends     org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader implements
org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean {

    protected String batchStatus;

    public void getBatchStatus(String batchStatus) {
            this.batchStatus = batchStatus;
    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        setSql("SELECT r.EDCBATCH_OPEN_DATETIME As openDate FROM rev_acq_edcbatch r WHERE r.EDCBATCH_STATUS ='" + batchStatus + "'");
    }

}
```

and then leave sql out of the bean definition and use setBatchStatus instead:

```
<bean id="notificationReader" class="EdcBatchItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="batchStatus" value="#{jobParameters['edcbatchStatus']}" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean name = "campaignMapper" class="rh.com.app.domain.AgingMapper">
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Best wishes
Marc

Answer (score 0):

PS the reason your code doesn't work is that Spring thinks #{jobParameters['edcbatchStatus']} is part of the SQL and doesn't interpret it. If you pass it as the complete value of a field it should work, assuming the syntax is correct.