# Using SpringBatch JdbcCursorItemReader with List as NamedParameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using below bean definition to configure a reader to read some data from the database table in a Spring Batch project. It is using a named param in SQL. I am passing A java.util.List as a parameter. However, I am getting Invalid Column type error when it tries to run the SQL.

If I just hard code one single value (`namedParameters.put("keys", "138219");` ) instead of passing a list, it works.

```
@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<MyDTO> myReader() {
JdbcCursorItemReader<MyDTO> itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
itemReader.setDataSource(myDatasource);
itemReader.setRowMapper(return new RowMapper<MyDTO>() {
    @Override
    public MyDTO mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
       return toMyDto(resultSet);
    }
};);


Map<String, Object> namedParameters = new HashMap<>();
List<Long> keys= //Some List
Map<String, List<Long>> singletonMap = Collections.singletonMap("keys", keys);
namedParameters.putAll(singletonMap);

itemReader.setSql(NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters("SELECT A FROM MYTABLE WHERE KEY IN (:keys)",new MapSqlParameterSource(namedParameters)));

ListPreparedStatementSetter listPreparedStatementSetter = new ListPreparedStatementSetter();
listPreparedStatementSetter.setParameters(
    Arrays.asList(NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray("SELECT A FROM MYTABLE WHERE KEY IN (:keys)", namedParameters)));

itemReader.setPreparedStatementSetter(listPreparedStatementSetter);
return itemReader;
}
```

I referred [sample code snippet here](https://github.com/benas/sandbox/blob/master/batch2521/src/test/java/com/example/demo/NamedParametersJdbcCursorItemReaderTest.java) as a response to one of the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222353/using-spring-batch-jdbccursoritemreader-with-namedparameters) asked - it is what seems to be working when we pass one value. However, my issue is with passing a list instead of one value in the param. This is where it seems to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListPreparedStatementSetter` is not aware of parameters types. If a parameter is an array or a collection, it will set it as is to the first placeholder, leaving other placeholders unset. Hence the error. In your example, if `List<Long> keys = Arrays.asList(1, 2)`, your sql statement will be:

```
SELECT A FROM MYTABLE WHERE KEY IN (?, ?)
```

If you pass your `singletonMap` to the `ListPreparedStatementSetter`, it will set the value of `keys` (which is of type `List`) to the first placeholder and that's it. The second placeholder will still be unset and the preparation of the statement will fail.

You can flatten parameters before passing them to the `ListPreparedStatementSetter` and it should work fine. I added a sample with how to flatten parameters before passing them to the prepared statement setter [here](https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-lab/blob/master/issues/batch2521/src/test/java/com/example/demo/NamedParametersJdbcCursorItemReaderAsListTest.java) (See `flatten` method).

Hope this helps.